# flask command not found in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, pypi

I am beginner in python flask. I tried to install flask with a long time . But it not installing properly.
Here I am mentioning my steps

Installed python 3.9.4
pip install Flask
made directory
created .py file and write demo code

on that directory if I run python in cmd, it shows
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

but if i run flask run, it shows
**bash: flask: command not found**

in app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

host = os.getenv('hostname')

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return f'hello22 {os.getenv("hostname")}'
```

Comment: Please, show how your code and how you "run flask"

Comment: Looks strange to me. What "Bash" are you using?

Comment: @HuLu ViCa if I run **python -m flask run** in cmd then it **Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000** . But problem is if I change anything in my code it's not effect on browser window after refresh page

Comment: @iBug git bash.

Comment: @ sogu . It's requirement to use flask

Comment: @Kabir git bash from git for windows?

Comment: @ unhandledguy, yes.

Comment: oh my god... Did you install your development environment in that Git Bash?? I *strongly* recommend WSL instead which would be far more realistic

Comment: @ iBug, Can I use windows power shell ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you're on Windows.

As [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#quickstart) says (for Flask>0.11) you need to:

1. Open CMD or Powershell
2. Run $env:FLASK_APP = "myapp.py"
3. Then *flask run* or *python -m flask run*

You are getting "bash: flask: command not found" because you're using git bash and it's and isolated enviroment, aside your Windows enviroment.

Check for:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Finally, if you want to see new changes after you update and save your new code, on your app config set debug as True or you can just:

1. Open CMD or Powershell
2. Run *set FLASK_ENV=development* or *set FLASK_DEBUG=1*

Comment: If i run **flask run** flask : The term 'flask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: But its working for **python -m flask run** . But problem is if I change anything in my code it's not effect on browser window after refresh page

Comment: Also tried with **set FLASK_ENV=development or set FLASK_DEBUG=1**

Comment: @Kabir Yes, both *flask run* or *python -m flask run* are valid options to start your flask app.

Can you update your question with a preview of your code?.

Comment: I am using windows power shell

Answer (score 1):

**Update, using Flask 2.3.2:**
I had a similar problem, which led me to this post. Studying the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/installation/#virtual-environments), the solution became evident to me. The `flask` command is provided by the `Click` framework, which is installed together with Flask. This framework and the `flask` command are only available from within the installation environment. Attempting to run the command in a terminal outside this environment will lead to a **command not found** error. If, as recommended and applied in my case, use is made of a virtual environment, it is also necessary to activate the latter. Here is a summary example that I prepared for my own reference:

Installation Prerequisites: Python 3.8 and newer.

Installation environment: Flask must be installed in the application environment. Setting up a virtual environment is recommended.

Example for creating an environment using a CLI:

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ py -3 -m venv .venv
```

Activate the environment:

```
$ .venv\Scripts\activate
```

Install Flask:

```
$ pip install Flask
```

Verification: Create an app in the environment, e.g. hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

Run the app at a command prompt within the environment:

```
$ flask --app hello run
```

When successful, the following message will be displayed:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'hello'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

I performed the above using a Git Bash terminal on Windows 10, with Python 3.11.3 installed.